# Returning the result of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

```
function main() {
  matchUserToChatRoom(senderID)
    .then(function(chatRoom) {
      //FIXME: I want to be able to use chatRoom from the below function
      console.log(chatRoom)
    })
}

function matchUserToChatRoom(userId) {
  return models.User.findOne({where: {messenger_id: userId}})
    .then(function(user) {
       models.ChatRoom
        .findOrCreate({where: {status: "open"}, defaults: {status: "open"}})
        .spread(function(chatRoom, created) {
          chatRoom.addUser(user).then(function(chatRoom) {
            //FIXME: I want to use this "chatRoom" inside the main function
          })
        })
     })
  })
}
```

How do I return the `chatRoom` object, which is a result of nested promises, to the main function?

Comment: Where do `findOrCreate` and `spread` come from? Is it a COTS or custom code?

Comment: @sp00m they are from sequelize. Both return a promise.

Comment: You don't "return" it. You "wait for" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not forget to return the promises in order to be *chained*.

```
function matchUserToChatRoom(userId) {
  return models.User.findOne({where: {messenger_id: userId}})
    .then(function(user) {
       return models.ChatRoom
        .findOrCreate({where: {status: "open"}, defaults: {status: "open"}})
        .spread(function(chatRoom, created) {
          return chatRoom.addUser(user);
        })
     })
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is for getting idea. You need to use `reject` too.

```
function matchUserToChatRoom(userId) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  models.User.findOne({where: {messenger_id: userId}})
    .then(function(user) {
       models.ChatRoom
        .findOrCreate({where: {status: "open"}, defaults: {status: "open"}})
        .spread(function(chatRoom, created) {
          chatRoom.addUser(user).then(function(chatRoom) {
             resolve(chatRoom);
            //FIXME: I want to use this "chatRoom" inside the main function
          })
        })
     })
  })
}
});
```

Comment: No, you **don't** need to create your own promise. That's the "promise constructor anti-pattern".